# Sum of prime number of factorials

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

Let $p$ be an arbitrary odd prime, prove that the following expression is divisible by $p$
$$1!+2!+\cdots+p!-\left[\frac{(p-1)!}{e}\right],$$
where $e$ is the base of the natural logarithm and $[\cdot]$ denotes the integer that is less than or equal to $\cdot$.

My thought: I think the key step is to estimate the last term in the floor function, we have 
$$\begin{align}
\frac{(p-1)!}{e}&=(p-1)!\times e^{-1}
\\&=(p-1)!\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}
\\&=(p-1)!\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}+(p-1)!\sum_{j=p}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}
\end{align}$$

I tested a few cases and it seems the first summand is equal to $\left[\frac{(p-1)!}{e}\right],$ but I am not sure how to deduce the remainder term (the second term) is less than unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an alternating series and so has absolute value bounded by the absolute value of the very first term, $|(p-1)!\frac{(-1)^p}{p!}|=\frac{1}{p}$.
And as you've probably noticed, the first $p$ terms work out to be $(p-1)!\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}=(-1)^j (j+1)\dots (p-1) \equiv (p-j-1)! \mod p$ which cancel out the $1!+\dots +(p-1)!$